# Sentence Understanding

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Balanced reporting requires impartially revealing injustices **where they occur no less than** fairly presenting the views of each party in a conflict.

I understand "Balanced...injustices" and "fairly...conflict" parts separately, but I do not understand what the sentence means as a whole because of the bold part (where...than). Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply means that for a balanced reporting, two things are **equally** important:

1. "impartially revealing injustices where they occur"
2. "fairly presenting the views of each party in a conflict".

Comment: Does the first sentence mean "In the places where injustices occur, balanced reporting should impartially reveal injustices"?

Comment: @user198952 Spot on.